# pymongo: findandmodify - "no such command" is returned

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I believe there is a bug in pymongo (or, at least, the documentation) which makes it impossible to run a `findandupdate` query.

Here's what happens. When I run:

```
    result = db.command({
        'findandmodify': 'my_collection',
        'query': {'foo': 'bar'},
        'update': {'$set': {'status': 'queued'}},
    })
```

The query that actually gets sent to the server is:

```
{ 'query': {'foo': 'bar'}, 'findandmodify': 'my_collection', … }
```

Note that the `query` argument is *first*, and `findandmodify` is *second*.

But this causes the server to throw up:

```
OperationFailure: command { 'query': {'foo': 'bar'}, 'findandmodify': 'my_collection', … } failed: no such cmd
```

Because the server expects `findandmodify` to be first (BSON dicts are, apparently, ordered).

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: What version of Mongo are you running?

Comment: Python `dict`s have no intrinsic ordering, so your remarks about "first" and "second" are, simply, complete nonsense in the context of the Python language.  Please clarify!

Comment: @Alex yes, that's the problem: Python's dicts are unordered, but (apperantly) BSON dicts (are they called dicts?) are.

Comment: Don't know BSON.  In JSON, which matches the Javascript specs, objects (the equivalent of dictionaries, except that keys must be specifically strings) are **not** ordered.

Comment: Ok, so the MongoDB docs (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON) aren't entirely clear on the matter… But Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) suggests that BSON objects are ordered, and the Mongo implementation seems to suggest the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For languages that don't have a built-in sorted dict type the mongo drivers include one. In python that is the SON type: http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.4%2B/api/pymongo/son.html. You will need to use that for all commands.

If that still fails make sure you are using the latest version of the database as findandmodify is a new feature.

Comment: reference to "current (build)" url http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/son.html

Comment: Now at: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/collection.py#L1384

Answer (score 3):

current pymongo api has find_and_modify built-in
see more at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/collection.py#L1035

Comment: and there are examples in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/test/test_collection.py#L1267

Answer (score 2):

One workaround may be to construct the JavaScript version of the command and pass it to db.eval().

```
db.eval('db.runCommand({"findandmodify": "my_collection", "query": {"foo": "bar"}, "update": {"$set": {"status": "queued"}},})')
```

The issue is that, as Alex mentioned, Python dicts have no order, so you will need to build the string more-or-less manually.

Comment: Javascript objects have no intrinsic ordering either (by language standards, though specific JS implementations are of course free to add any arbitrary one -- point is, no guarantees about it!).

Comment: The jS standard says the order is undefined, but most implementations preserve the order you add elements to the object in. In either case, this example works correctly with Mongo's interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

See PyMongo documentation:

> Note the order of keys in the command document is significant (the
>   “verb” must come first), so commands which require multiple keys (e.g.
>   findandmodify) should use an instance of SON or a string and kwargs
>   instead of a Python dict.

http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.1/api/pymongo/database.html